# Automatically generate calls to SwaggerDoc in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers(); //this replaces these services.AddMvcCore().AddApiExplorer();
        ...
        services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            // make this automatic ???
            options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Version = "v1", Title = "v1 API", Description = "v1 API Description" });
            options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Version = "v2", Title = "v2 API", Description = "v2 API Description" });
            ...
            options.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
            {
                var versions = desc.CustomAttributes().OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>().SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions).ToArray();
                var maps = desc.CustomAttributes().OfType<MapToApiVersionAttribute>().SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions).ToArray();
                return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version) && (!maps.Any() || maps.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version));
            });
        });
    }
```

This code works as expected. But can the calls to `SwaggerDoc` be automated, in order to make the code more generic? In `DocInclusionPredicate` from the `desc` parameter the versions can be gathered.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `ApiVersionAttribute`, I assume you are using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` nuget package. The package provides a service named `IApiVersionDescriptionProvider`. This service provides an enumeration of all detected API-Versions. You can then automatically add them as a swagger-doc.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // you can use the IApiVersionDescriptionProvider
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider()
        .GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        var info = new Info
        {
            Title = $"My API {description.ApiVersion}",
            Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
            Contact = new Contact
            {
                Email = "info@mydomain.com",
                Name = "Foo Bar",
                Url = "https://thecatapi.com/"
            }
        };

        options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, info);
    }

    // instead of manually adding your versions
    //options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Version = "v1", Title = "v1 API", Description = "v1 API Description" });
    //options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Version = "v2", Title = "v2 API", Description = "v2 API Description" });
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) =>
    {
        var versions = desc.CustomAttributes().OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>().SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions).ToArray();
        var maps = desc.CustomAttributes().OfType<MapToApiVersionAttribute>().SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions).ToArray();
        return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version) && (!maps.Any() || maps.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version));
    });
});
```